# Windows Batch script leaves console window open

Tags: windows, batch-file, nginx, php

I'm trying to set up a friends Windows 7 computer to run Nginx & PHP5. I found a script online for starting and stopping Nginx & PHP, after adding the directory change line I was able to make it work. However, there seems to be an issue causing it to leave the second  console window that starts PHP open. Is there a way to make that console window close?

Batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF

CD C:\nginx

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq nginx.exe" | find /I "nginx.exe" > NUL && (
    GOTO STOP
) || (
    GOTO START
)

:START
ECHO Starting nginx
start nginx
ECHO Starting PHP
start php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini
GOTO DONE

:STOP
ECHO Stopping nginx
start nginx -s quit
ECHO Stopping PHP
taskkill /f /IM php-cgi.exe

:DONE
TIMEOUT 3
```

Comment: Place an `exit` command after the `timeout` line.  Is that what you need to do?

Comment: @foxidrive I tried that as well, but the window just stays open?

Comment: `php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini` <--- type that at a cmd prompt in `C:\nginx` .  Does the prompt come back?  If not then it is the exe running.

Comment: @foxidrive yes it stays open

Comment: I edited my comment.  If the prompt doesn't return then the window is running the server and that's the reason why the window doesn't close.

Comment: @foxidrive the cursor just goes on to the next line and blinks like its waiting...

Comment: `cmd /c php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini` <-- try this in the batch file instead.  The prompt is returning as you have described. **edit** see malexander's answer.  He's found more info.

Comment: @foxidrive same thing. Just seen an updated answer and the way PHP CGI is programmed it stays open and listens for connections. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [/b parameter](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) on `START` to start the application without opening another cmd window

```
START /b php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini
```

**Update:**
It appears this is the behavior of php-cgi.exe. See this article for the full story and workaround. http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFastCGIOnWindows

> After being launched, php-cgi.exe will keep listening for connections
>   in a command prompt window. To hide that window, use the tiny utility
>   RunHiddenConsole

Basically, you just need to d/l and unzip [RunHiddenConsole](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/attachments/660/RunHiddenConsole.zip) to your nginx directory, then change this line to:

```
RunHiddenConsole.exe php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini
```

Comment: The window is still open.

Comment: It appears this is the behavior of php-cgi.exe. See this article for the full story and workaround.  http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFastCGIOnWindows

Comment: The `/B` parameter does work to hide the php-cgi cmd window (using Windows 10 and PHP 7.2.5).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for

```
start php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini 
/exit b
```

Comment: start php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini && exit

Comment: That just exited the script right away and the PHP CGI window stays open.

Answer (score 0):

To run a .BAT Invisible you can use a simple vbs script.

Put this in a .VBS file :

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

And then run your BAT like this :

```
wscript.exe "C:\invisible.vbs" "C:\YourBat.bat"
```